# How is postfix relay configured by default on OSX?

Tags: postfix, mac-osx, smtp

On OSX, I don't need to configure postfix at all, I just `sudo postfix start` and it all works. In the log files, I see

```
Apr 23 14:04:46 orcrist.local postfix/smtp[19506]: 9211B2E4B96C: to=<me@example.com>, relay=mail.example.com[192.168.1.201]:25, delay=0.07, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 38571E7C7D3)
```

How is `relay` set?

The `postconf -d` doesn't reveal any parameters defined with that IP, so postfix must determine it at runtime and/or using some other tool. Grepping in `/etc` doesn't reveal any files with the IP `192.168.1.201` except `resolv.conf`, but changing that file to some other IP doesn't generate a true negative.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both parts where you obfuscated the real domain name are actually the same name (example.com and mail.example.com) the likely situation is that you are using internal nameservers (which is 192.168.1.201) that have an MX record defined for whatever example.com really is and it's simply using that record.

That's how SMTP normally works when delivering remotely.